# Installed GNOME 3 ppa on Ubuntu 16.04 now cannot log-in to Ubuntu 16.04 anymore

Tags: gnome, 16.04, login-screen

I am running (or was) Ubuntu 16.04 and wanted to try out GNOME. I think I might have messed things up here by adding the GNOME 3 ppa. What I **intended** to do was get it so that when I restart, I would be able to choose whether to log-in to either GNOME or Ubuntu. Now, when I restart, I see **only** the GNOME footprint. Furthermore, when I click on the footprint, I **do not** see a click down menu to be able to log-in to Ubuntu at all. See attached images. Please help me with this.

[image: GNOME login]

[image: GNOME login attempt to login to Ubuntu]

-Michael D

Comment: Did you try clicking on the Gnome foot icon?

Comment: Yes.  Upon doing that, I get the second picture. I then had to click on something in the upper left hand corner of the screen (I have forgotten what at the moment) in order to restore the footprint icon and get the password panel back so I could at least log-in to GNOME. But still could not log-in to Ubuntu.

Comment: From my experience, Unity and Gnome don't play well being installed together.  I had to reinstall when I tried adding Gnome with Unity.  I shrank my partitions to add a 3rd OS  to my system and installed Ubuntu Gnome fresh to try it out.  I'll be deleting my Ubuntu(Unity) OS soon because I much prefer Gnome.  Have you tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to get the Unity login screen back?

Comment: Upon trying that now when I login the I see the Ubuntu logo and 5 orange dots then that's all it freezes there. Ugh.

Comment: On the grub menu select advanced options, then recovery, then drop to root shell. Then do the same thing but gdm instead of lightdm. But then you're back where you started. So do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and reboot.

Comment: Don't think I'm getting as far as the Grub menu.

Comment: When you first turn on the computer, keep pressing SHIFT for the grub menu to appear.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have tried both holding  Shift and constantly pressing shift but it goes straight  into the Ubuntu  screen with the 5 dots and freezes there.

Comment: Ok, try the same but with the ESCAPE key.

Comment: Never mind. Didn't get much sleep last night. So far I am in a root shel.

Comment: Now I'm getting : "unable  to locate package  reintall"  "unable to locate package ubuntu" and "unable to locate package   desktop".

Comment: Did you type it exactly as I did?  It sounds like you're typing `...install reinstall` instead of `...install --reinstall`.  Don't forget the two dashes, and the dash between ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: Here is what I get: [terminal](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipOx5Ks47AbyhZMSXrOONu3d_OxjGah-QNDCs-qg)

Comment: Link doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41734/discussion-between-dorian-and-michael-dykes).

Comment: An alternative is to switch to a console at the login screen with CTRL+ALT+F1 (up to F6) login and then issue the command to reinstall the ubuntu desktop. I would recommend using sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^ (notice the carat (^) next to desktop).

Additionally you don't need the Ubuntu GNOME PPA's unless you want the bleeding edge which will still be under development for the next release. Try using the ppa-purge package to remove Ubuntu GNOME staging PPA and then install the ubuntu-gnome-desktop package which is the stable release version for 16.04.